# Convert shell script to python script

Tags: python, bash

This is my code of bash which I want to convert into python...

```
    IFS='-' read -r -a tests <<<"${test_type}"
for t in "${tests[@]}"; do
    test_method="${t#*:}"
    test="${t%%:*}"
    case "$test" in
        tls)
            test_file="$test"AuthTest.py
            ;;
        *)
            test_file="$test"Test.py
            ;;
    esac
```

The main thing is that I am not able to understand this portion of code exactly what it is doing:

```
for t in "${tests[@]}"; do
    test_method="${t#*:}"
    test="${t%%:*}"
```

what will be value of test_method and test ?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. What have you tried in Python, and what problems are you having with that code ?

Comment: You haven't even supplied the whole code.  Where does `test_type` come from, and what format is it in?  Rather than convert line-by-line, it is better to go back to the design and implement it again in Python.  There is not necessarily a one-to-one command relationship between languages.

Comment: test_type is variable only that supposed to be list in python.

Comment: The main thing is that I am not getting this portion of the code.                                  for t in "${tests[@]}"; do
    test_method="${t#*:}"
    test="${t%%:*}"

Comment: This looks like unit testing, use an according library in Python for that. Don't reinvent that wheel unless you have a compelling reason for it.

Comment: Please explain me what "${t#*:}" and "${t%%:*}" are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tackle your broader question of feasibility, let's look at your script's functionality.

Basically your script does the following:

1. Reads in some data separated by `-`, splitting it up.
2. Loops through these lines doing string substitution.
3. Carries out some conditional logic based on these results.

Yes, this is all very doable in `Python`.  Be aware, though, that `Python` doesn't have a traditional `case` construct (one of its quirks).

Regarding your more specific question of "what `"${t#*:}"` and `"${t%%:*}"` are doing", read this for background:
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

`"${t#*:}"` deletes the shortest stretch of any characters preceding a ':'
`"${t%%:*}"` deletes the LONGEST stretch of any characters after ':'

Here's a silly example to illustrate this:

```
$!/bin/bash
var='jim:bob:cujo:smith'
echo ${var#*:}
echo ${var%%:*}
```

Result:

```
bob:cujo:smith
jim
```

Again, of course this can be done in Python, and almost assuredly more succinctly, but you're going to have to learn how to use python regular expressions and built-in commands.